# getting the value from two inputs in JS calculator

Tags: javascript

creating a vanilla JS calculator for class and I've gotten the number and operator values to show in the display. Having trouble working out the logic for my operators as when they're clicked they shouldn't show up in the display but fire an event listener to the proper operator and show the answer when = is clicked. For starters I'm just focusing on adding 1 + 2 = 3.

```
<div id="calculator-container">   
    <div>
         <input id='calculator-display' type="text" value='' placeholder='0' disabled />
    </div>        
        <div id="calculator-buttons">
            <input type="button" class='number-button' id='one' value='1' />
            <input type="button" class='number-button' id='two' value='2' />
            <input type="button" class='number-button' id='three' value='3' />
            <input type="button" class='number-button'  id='four' value='4' />
            <input type="button" class='number-button'  id='five' value='5' />
            <input type="button" class='number-button'  id='six' value='6' />
            <input type="button" class='number-button'  id='seven' value='7' />
            <input type="button" class='number-button'  id='eight' value='8' />
            <input type="button" class='number-button'  id='nine' value='9' />
            <input type="button" class='number-button'  id='zero' value='0' />
            <input type="button" class='number-button'  id='decimal' value='.' />
            <input type="button" class='operator-button'  id='times' value='&times' />
            <input type="button" class='operator-button'  id='divide' value='&divide' />
            <input type="button" class='operator-button'  id='add' value='+' />
            <input type="button" class='operator-button'  id='minus' value='-' />
            <input type="button" class='operator-button'  id='equal' value='=' />
            <input type="button" class='operator-button'  id='clear' value='AC' />
        </div>
</div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>


const display = document.getElementById('calculator-display');
let firstNumber = null;
let secondNumber = null;
let operand = null;

function numberButtonClicked() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.number-button').forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            display.value += e.target.value;
        })
    })
};

function allClear() {
    document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function() {
        if(!display.value == '') {
            display.value = '';
        }
    });
}


function operatorClicked() {
    const operator = document.querySelectorAll('.operator-button');
    operator.forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            display.value = e.target.value;
        })
    })
}


operatorClicked();
allClear();
numberButtonClicked();
```

Comment: the question of calculators is recurrent on this site, take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63724014/i-am-trying-to-make-a-calculator-in-javascript-but-it-is-not-working-somehow/63724685#63724685

Comment: `!display.value == ''` is equivalent to `true`, because the boolean produced by negating `display.value` is abstractly equal to the empty string. `!=` is the “not (abstractly) equals” operator, `!==` is the strict “not equals” one, and `if(display.value)` may be a shorter version of what you intend to do.