# Advice on flawed logic per JavaScript calculator

Tags: javascript, html

How do I improve my logic for building my calculator? I cannot figure out how to integrate sin/cos/tan/percents correctly. This is my first real java script assignment and I am not sure how to go about handling all the errors I get. I frequently get not a number as the result. I know I cannot read everything into a variable to handle the calculations. But I don't know where to go from here.

```js
function in1() {
  document.calc.txt.value += '1'
}

function in2() {
  document.calc.txt.value += '2'
}

function in3() {
  document.calc.txt.value += '3'
}

function in4() {
  document.calc.txt.value += '4'
}

function in5() {
  document.calc.txt.value += '5'
}

function in6() {
  document.calc.txt.value += '6'
}

function in7() {
  document.calc.txt.value += '7'
}

function in8() {
  document.calc.txt.value += '8'
}

function in9() {
  document.calc.txt.value += '9'
}


function inAdd() {
  document.calc.txt.value += '+'
}

function inSub() {
  document.calc.txt.value += '-'
}

function inMult() {
  document.calc.txt.value += '*'
}

function inDiv() {
  document.calc.txt.value += '/'
}

function inDecimal() {
  document.calc.txt.value += '.'
}

flag = 0;

function inSin() {
  document.calc.txt.value += 'Sin('
  flag = 1
}

function inCos() {
  document.calc.txt.value += 'Cos('
  flag = 2
}

function inTan() {
  document.calc.txt.value += 'Tan('
  flag = 3
}

function inPercent() {


  document.calc.txt.value = calc.txt.value / 100;
}


var inputTest = document.getElementById("").value;

function equals() {

  if (flag == 1) {
    var input = calc.txt.value;
    var newNumber = input.substring(4);
    document.calc.txt.value = Math.sin(newNumber);
    flag = 0
  }

  if (flag == 2) {
    var input = calc.txt.value;
    var newNumber = input.substring(4);
    document.calc.txt.value = Math.cos(newNumber);
    flag = 0
  }

  if (flag == 3) {
    var input = calc.txt.value;
    var newNumber = input.substring(4);
    document.calc.txt.value = Math.tan(newNumber);
    flag = 0
  } else if (flag == 0) {
    document.calc.txt.value = (eval(calc.txt.value))
  }
}
```

```css
.flexBoxContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.title {
  border: black 5px solid;
  color: red;
  padding: 2px;
  font-size: 21;
  width: 310px;
  text-align: center;
}

.calculator {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.calculator .keys {
  border: white 3px ridge;
  height: 60px;
  width: 75px;
}

.input-box {
  border: white 3px ridge;
  height: 60px;
  width: 236px;
  flex-basis: 66%;
}

.input-display {
  border: black 3px solid;
  background-color: white;
  height: 45px;
  width: 233x;
  flex-basis: 66%;
  text-align: right;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  ;
}

.container1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

@media (min-width: 381px) {
  .calculator {
    width: 380px;
  }
}


/* button formatting below */

.button1 {
  border: black 10px solid;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 1px 19px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 36px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button2 {
  border: black 10px solid;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 1px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.buttonSin {
  border: black 10px solid;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 1px 7px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.buttonCos {
  border: black 10px solid;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 1px 3px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.buttonTan {
  border: black 10px solid;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 1px 2px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button3 {
  border: black 10px solid;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 1px 17px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.buttonMinus {
  border: black 10px solid;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 1px 22px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.buttonDiv {
  border: black 10px solid;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 1px 21px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.buttonDec {
  border: black 10px solid;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 1px 23px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.buttonPer {
  border: black 10px solid;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 1px 12px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html>

<title>JavaScript Calculator Assignment</title>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="calculator.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="calculator.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="flexBoxContainer">

  <form class="calculator" name="calc">

    <div class="title">JavaScript Calculator</div>

    <div class="container1">
      <div class="input-box  center">
        <input class="value input-box center" type="text" name="txt" readonly="">
        <!--<span class ="" onclick="document.calc.txt.value +=''"></span> <!--do we need this?-->
      </div>

      <div class="keys">
        <span class="button1" onclick="document.calc.txt.value =''">c</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="keys">
      <span class="button2" onclick="in1()">1</span>
    </div>

    <div class="keys">
      <span class="button2" onclick="in2()">2</span>
    </div>

    <div class="keys">
      <span class="button2" onclick="in3()">3</span>
    </div>

    <div class="keys">
      <span class="buttonSin" onclick="inSin()">Sin</span>
    </div>

    <div class="keys">
      <span class="button2" onclick="in4()">4</span>
    </div>

    <div class="keys">
      <span class="button2" onclick="in5()">5</span>
    </div>

    <div class="keys">
      <span class="button2" onclick="in6()">6</span>
    </div>

    <div class="keys">
      <span class="buttonCos" onclick="inCos()">Cos</span>
    </div>

    <div class="keys">
      <span class="button2" onclick="in7()">7</span>
    </div>

    <div class="keys">
      <span class="button2" onclick="in8()">8</span>
    </div>

    <div class="keys">
      <span class="button2" onclick="in9()">9</span>
    </div>

    <div class="keys">
      <span class="buttonTan" onclick="inTan()">Tan</span>
    </div>

    <div class="keys">
      <span class="button3" onclick="inAdd()">+</span>
    </div>

    <div class="keys">
      <span class="buttonMinus" onclick="inSub()">-</span>
    </div>

    <div class="keys">
      <span class="button2" onclick="inMult()">*</span>
    </div>

    <div class="keys">
      <span class="buttonDiv" onclick="inDiv()">/</span>
    </div>

    <div class="keys">
      <span class="buttonDec" onclick="inDecimal()">.</span>
    </div>

    <div class="keys">
      <span class="button2" onclick="document.calc.txt.value +='0'">0</span>
    </div>

    <div class="keys">
      <span class="button3" onclick="equals()"> = </span>
    </div>

    <div class="keys">
      <span class="buttonPer" onclick="inPercent()">%</span>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: What is this line for: `var inputTest = document.getElementById("").value;`

Comment: the question of calculators is recurrent on this site, take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63724014/i-am-trying-to-make-a-calculator-in-javascript-but-it-is-not-working-somehow/63724685#63724685